# Understanding static friction in this problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, friction

[image]
Suppose we have the following system, in which we know the masses of A and B, and we know the static friction coefficient between A and C(there's no friction between the table and A).
What's the minimum mass of C that prevents A from moving?
So, just writing the free body diagrams and writing the equations I get that $m_c$ must be greater than $\dfrac{m_b}{\mu_e}$, which is okay for me.
Now, the problem comes when I analyze what happens to C. Since there's no other horizontal force on  C besides the static friction, I assume C must move to the left. However, this goes against my intuition/life experience, in that it's impossible for C to move without A moving.
Does C really move? Why/Why not?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. Block A will always move no matter what the mass of C is. Are you sure you have the problem correct?

Comment: Why would A always move? Isn't it possible that C is so heavy that it prevents A from moving?

Comment: No. Even if C is really heavy A will still move.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Could you elaborate on this? Isn't the static friction up to $\mu m_cg$, so if I make m_c big enough I can counter the tension $T$? (Thus making the system static)

Comment: The maximum static friction is $\mu N$. That is the largest it can be before slipping occurs. It's a common mistake among students to say static friction is always equal to $\mu N$.

Comment: I do know its maximum value is $\mu N$. In this case $N=m_cg$, so it's maximum value is $\mu m_cg$. As far as I know, the static friction can reach up to that value to prevent movement. So, if I make $m_c$  big enough, the maximum value will increase, and thus, the tension will not cause any problem to the friction, cause it will always match it.

Comment: "Since there's no horizontal force on C besides the static friction, I assume C must move to the left" so you have already shown that if there is any static friction force, C will move, which will allow A to move. Then how can C ever be heavy enough to prevent A from moving?

Comment: If you have one gallon of water in a two-gallon tank, and then you increase the size of the tank to four gallons, you still only have one gallon of water. Increasing the maximum volume the tank can hold doesn't change how much water you have.

Comment: @Alwin I think I understand this line of reasoning.Since C starts sliding to the left, the friction on C now becomes dynamic and changes its direction to the right. Thus, the friction on A acts to the left, adding itself to the tension, and making A move to the left. What I don't end up getting is how it's possible that, no matter how small $m_b$ is, or how big $m_c$ is, A will move.. I really can't get around that

Comment: This is the power of being frictionless! Imagine A and C locked together tightly as a single mass. No matter how large A and C are, it has finite mass. And B provides a finite force. Finite force will always accelerate a finite mass. Imagine a small force in space, if that helps :)

Comment: The force on A will still be T - (Friction). The force on C will still be (Friction). Even if it doesn't become dynamic, even though it does not change direction, (Friction) cannot defeat T, because A must always accelerate more than C, since A drags C.

Comment: Friction acting on A won't act in the direction of Tension.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine there is no C. Then masses A and B may accelerate, so that Bg = (A+B)a, where a is the acceleration of A (and hence the acceleration of B, since they are tied by a string). B has total force (Bg-T) and A has force T, so
$(Bg-T) = Ba$ and $T = Aa$, leading to $Bg = (A+B)a$.

Now imagine there is C and they all move together. By similar logic,
$Bg = (A+B+C)a$. As long as there is no friction between the table and A, what could possibly prevent the combined A+C from moving?

Now imagine there is C and somehow A and B slip away from C. This happens if the friction necessary to accelerate C to keep up with A and B is larger than the static friction. In that case, the A-C interface will no longer be static, and A will pull away from C.

$Cg\mu < Ca = \frac{CBg}{A+B+C}$

so

$\mu < \frac{B}{A+B+C}$

When B is too large, it's like doing the tablecloth (A) yank/pull trick and leaving the plates on top (C) behind.

Comment: The problem asks about A moving, not C moving.

Comment: I agree with you. I chose to address the system and the title "understanding static friction in this problem" rather than the specifics about the problem, which you have also identified may be fallible.